# How to check if a file is database in android programmatically?

Tags: android

How can I check If a file that I have selected from the list of files is database type or not in android ? The others files may be a text file, apk file or can be of any format. I assume not depending upon the extension of the file like .txt, .apk, .pdf etc as extension of the file can be changed also.
Thank You..!!

Comment: You can compare extensions like .sql, .db and all

Comment: Check if it contains a string like "create table" etc. and other related query although the probability of correctness might be 92%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a subclass of *SQLiteOpenHelper*, you can create a new object with the file in question, and then call *getReadableDatabase ()*.
If tha file is a database, no exception will be thrown.
Otherwise, a *SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException* will be trhown.

So you can surround your code with a try-catch block, and if an exception is thrown, then that file is not a database; otherwise, it is.

Answer (score 1):

check by extension of file. Normally database file has extension as .db , .sql etc